# Change Part of a Href on Hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a links (mysite.com/#page-1, #page-2...). I whant to change this to /page-1, /page-2 on hover respectively (# -> /).
Is it possible?

I was trying to go this way:

```
$('.page-link').hover(function() {
    var text = $(this).href();
    $(this).href(href.replace('#', '')); 
});
```

Comment: `href.replace` should be `text.replace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes **2** functions; one for `in`, one for `out`.

```
$('.page-link').hover(

  // mousein
  function() {

    // cache the original href
    $(this).data("href", $(this).attr("href"));

    // replace the existing href
    $(this).attr("href", function(idx, val) {

      // regexp match the page number
      // $1 will be set to literal string "#page-"
      // $2 will be a string of the page number
      return val.replace(/(#page-)(\d+)$/, function(str, $1, $2) {

        // parse as int and increment by 1
        return $1 + (parseInt($2, 10) + 1);
      });
    });
  },

  // mouseout
  function() {

    // restore the original href from the "cache"
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).data("href"));

    // clear the cache
    $(this).data("href", null);
  }
);
```

Demo time, right?

```js
$('.page-link').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).data("href", $(this).attr("href"));
    $(this).attr("href", function(idx, val) {
      return val.replace(/(#page-)(\d+)$/, function(str, $1, $2) {
        return $1 + (parseInt($2, 10) + 1);
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).data("href"));
    $(this).data("href", null);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#page-1" class="page-link">next page</a>
<a href="#page-2" class="page-link">next page</a>
<a href="#page-50" class="page-link">next page</a>
```

If you have content before the `#page-N` portion of the `href`, like this:

```
<a href="blahblah/#page-1">...</a>
```

You will need to adjust the `.replace` call to this

```
return val.replace(/^(.*#page-)(\d+)$/, function(str, $1, $2) {
  return $1 + (parseInt($2, 10) + 1);
});
```

This will make sure the the *entire* `href` is updated (not just replaced by the `#page-N` portion). This type of annoyance could be avoided if JavaScript RegExp supported [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but sadly it does not.

---

All that said tho, you should probably calculate the necessary pagination instead of trying to figure it out after-the-fact in the HTML